# Content-Disposition field missing in EML file. How do I treat this an an Attachment?

Tags: mime-types, content-disposition, eml

I have an eml sample file which has an attachment but the content-disposition field is missing. The Microsoft Outlook treats the below mentioned body part as Attachment and displays the attachment file in the header field.

```
    -----AU_MimePart_103082203221047146891954745
    Content-Type: text/html;
        charset=utf-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

//stream data

-----AU_MimePart_103082203221047146891954745--
```

How do I identify it as an attachment when the content-disposition filed is missing?